# How can I make A_Index start from a value greater than 1?

Tags: autohotkey

I have an autohotkey script that goes like this:

```
Loop, 1000  
{  
    Send, analyze %A_Index% {Enter}  
}
```

Occasionally I will need to start from a later analysis. However, I don't want to have to do all the previous analyses first. For example, I might want to start from analysis 970, and proceed through to the 1000th analysis.

I intend to manually alter the script every time I need to start from a later analysis.

Is there some way I can change the script so that it does this? I tried changing the reference to A_Index to be instead to A_Index+970, i.e.

```
Loop, 1000  
{  
    Send, analyze %A_Index+970% {Enter}  
}
```

However, then AutoHotKey just returned an error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to store the value first then use it

```
Loop, 1000  
{ 
    MyIndex :=  A_Index+970
    Send, analyze %MyIndex% {Enter}  
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: You can also use an expression, which doesn't require an additional variable: `Send % "analyze " (A_Index+970) " {Enter}"`

Comment: @MCL +1 for mentioning that.

Comment: @JoeDF +1 for mentioning +1 for mentioning that :)